# Handling null values in Command.ExecuteScalar using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get some values from the database but when no values are returned i get this error" "Specified cast is not valid"  but the code works fine when data comes back from the database specially when Checked = 1 is true.  How can i overcome  with null values  in Command.ExecuteScalar?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = @"select DATEDIFF(minute, Min(FullDatetime), Max(FullDatetime)) / 60.0 as hours                 
                      from   myTable
                       where userid = @UserID
                        and DT_Submitted = (select CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME))
                         and Checked = 1";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", tempUser.ToString());
                    con.Open();
                    decimal result = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    lblHours.Text = result.ToString("0.#") + " Hours";

                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

it is failing at this line

```
decimal result = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Check for null before you attempt to cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're coupling code from the view to code in the database which is not good practice. If this is a small practice app, keep it as is. Otherwise I recommend breaking the code into different classes so that the method calling the database can be reused in different parts of your app.
To achieve what you want, you need to check for null before you attempt to cast. This example should work but you should really look into how to create a method so that it can be reused. It also makes a big assumption that if null is returned from the database it is to be set to zero.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"select DATEDIFF(minute, Min(FullDatetime), Max(FullDatetime)) / 60.0 as hours                 
        from   myTable
        where userid = @UserID
        and DT_Submitted = (select CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME))
        and Checked = 1";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", tempUser.ToString());

        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        var hours = result != null ? (decimal)result : Decimal.Zero;
        lblHours.Text = hours.ToString("0.#")  + " Hours";
    }
}
```

Comment: Joel, i am getting error " no overload method 'ToString takes 1 argument'.  It does not like this part:   result.ToString("0.#")

Comment: This is because I removed the cast to decimal and therefore the `Object` returned from `ExecuteScalar` did not have an overloaded `ToString()` method to handle this call. I have readded the cast to decimal.